# no se me actualiza el registro PDO

Tags: php, pdo

hola amigos de la comunidad tengo un problema estoy haceindo un UPDATE pero el problema es que me brinca para la alerta de una vez y no me actualiza el registro el me recibes los parametros bien el único problema es a la hora de realizar el UPDATE anexo el codigo para ver que estoy haciendo mal.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['actualizar'])){
$sql=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET cedula=:cedula, nombres=:nombres, apellidos=:apellidos,    email=:email WHERE id = :id");


$sql->bindParam(':cedula',$_GET['cedula']);
$sql->bindParam(':nombres',$_GET['nombres']);
$sql->bindParam(':apellidos',$_GET['apellidos']);
$sql->bindParam(':email',$_GET['email']);
$sql->bindParam(':id',$_GET['id']);
$sql->execute();
if($sql)
{
echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Bien Hecho: Registro actualizado Correctamente !
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;index.php");
}
else
{
echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro no se pudo actualizar ! 
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;index.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Creo que el problema es esto: `WHERE id = :id`. Ponlo así: `WHERE id =:id`.

Comment: No hagas preguntas en las respuestas: Y el código correcto sería: `if (!$sql) { print_r($DB_con->errorInfo()); }` ...estaba mal el anterior... y lo puedes poner justo después del `prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

No puedo creeer cual era el error:

resulta que mi archivo se llama **actualizar** y el valor que tiene el input es **`name="actualizar"`** en el `if(isset($_GET['actualizar']))` por eso cada vez que la página entraba se actualizaba sola  jeje lo he editado a

```
if(isset($_GET['edita']))
name="edita"
```

y funciona de maravilla jejeejej tremendo lio